# Can't find where the default color schemes folder is for Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

So I decided to install Sublime text 2 alongside Sublime text 3 just to see if I could find where the `Color Scheme - Default` folder was for sublime text 2 and I found it without a problem (`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Color Scheme - Default`). But when I went into the `AppData/Sublime Text 3` folder to find the `Color Scheme - Default` folder it was nowhere to be seen. Does anybody know where this folder could be?

**Note:** I have checked in the installation directory (`C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3`) just to make sure that I was not missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

under

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Sublime Text 3\Cache
```

On my installation. However the file inside is a .cache file and binary.  I am searching the rest of my drive now for a more useful version!

I think the file (mostly xml format) you really want is this one 'Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package' under:

```
C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages
```

As the forum post says at https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/edit-tmtheme-in-sublime-text-3/10999 - these package files are just zip files containing the .tmTheme files:
[image]

Comment: Yeah, you are right it is only `.cache` files. and not the `.tmTheme` files.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have figured it out. That ResourceViewer package really helped a lot.